# Formatting issues with MultiLabelBinarizer() after reading CSV into Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I'd like to use MultiLabelBinarizer() to prepare a column containing labels that apply to a text. For example, predicting which genres a movie might fall under based on the [title](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2019/04/predicting-movie-genres-nlp-multi-label-classification/).

MultiLabelBinarizer() works great when the values are pre-defined as a list in the DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

df = pd.DataFrame({"Text": ["Blah blah", "Blah blah blah"],
              "Tag": [["Hi", "Hello"], ["Hey"]]})

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
print(mlb.fit_transform(df["Tag"]))
print(mlb.classes_)
```

Gives

```
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]])

array(['Hello', 'Hey', 'Hi'], dtype=object)
```

However, this approach fails when I'm reading a CSV or Excel file into Pandas. For example, if I make a simple CSV with the same structure:

[image: Example of CSV]

And read it into Pandas + use MultiLabelBinarizer():

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath)

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
print(mlb.fit_transform(df["Tag"]))
print(mlb.classes_)
```

It treats each character as a separate class and also doesn't output as array() anymore:

```
[[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1]]

[' ' '"' ',' 'H' 'e' 'i' 'l' 'o' 'y']
```

Given this limitation, how can I read from a CSV or Excel file and preserve the functionality of MultiLabelBinarizer()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add .str.split(",")

```
mlb.fit_transform(df["Tag"].str.split(","))
```

Comment: Thanks! I needed to strip the whitespace as well: ```mlb.fit_transform(df["Tag"].str.replace(" ","").str.split(","))```